Values of trig functions for integer radian values
There are plenty of tables that give the values of the main six trig functions: sin, cos, tan, cot, sec, csc. -- All the tables I've seen, the values are given for the common angles in degrees. Example: 30, 45, 60, 90, etc. Table Example
I'm trying to make a table of these trig values for myself, but I'm looking for their values associated with the first 6 radian integer values: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 radians.
What are the trig function values for the first 6 radian integers?
EDIT: My resulting table below.


You can always get the values from WolframAlpha or any Scientific calculator.

What can be the use of those values???

There's nothing significant about integer radian values.  As integer radians will be "transcendental" in relation to rotations of a circle, none of these values will be calculable by algebraic and/or geometric methods.  But calculus methods can approximate them.  Just use any old scientific calculator. $\sin 1=  0.8414709848078965066525023216303; \sin 2 = 0.90929742682568169539601986591174$ etc.....

The trig table you linked to explicitly gives radian measures to all of its angles, as well as measurements in degrees. The angles are chosen for their usefulness, not for the fact that the degree measurements happen to be integers.

$1$ radian is equal to $\frac {\pi}{\pi}\approx \frac {\pi}{\frac {22}7} \approx \frac {7\pi}{22}$.  You can try figuring that but... why?.   Also $360^\circ = 2\pi rad$ so $1 rad = \frac {360^\circ}{2\pi} = 57^\circ$ so you can try that.  But again ... why?  I think you are under the mistaken belief there is something significant to integer radians.  There isn't.
